# Comparing pandas dates after loading dataframe from parquet

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code that loads a pandas dataframe from a parquet file. The parquet file has a column called `the_date` and I'm trying to create a new dataframe filtering by date.

```
df = pd.read_parquet('path/to/file.parquet')
start_date = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
df2 = df[df['the_date'] > start_date]
```

Problem is that `df2` has all the `df` records and not filtered at all. Is there any type of date conversion needed after loading the dataframe from parquet? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandasdocs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) could be used.

Your code would then presumably be:

```
df = pd.read_parquet('path/to/file.parquet')
start_date = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
df['the_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['the_date']) # And any other parameters required to read the date
df2 = df[df['the_date'] > start_date]
```

A great way also to understand data formats is to use df.info() which should tell you the format